# android gradle error:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':libs' (needed by module 'app'.)

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to import this [physical web android project](https://github.com/google/physical-web/tree/master/android) into my android studio, but getting this error :

`Error:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':libs' (needed by module 'app'.)`

I haven't changed anything in the project.

Please help.

UPDATE :

If I run `./gradelw ---stacktrace installDebug`, I am getting this error :

```
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Unknown source file : ...while parsing org/physical_web/collection/BitmapRequest$RequestCallback.class
Unknown source file : 1 error; aborting
```

Why it's having problem with `RequestCallback` class, I haven't even touched the code after cloning.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in `https://github.com/google/physical-web/blob/master/android/PhysicalWeb/settings.gradle` it tries to import `../../java/libs` as project `:libs`, so you have to make sure it is where expected. If it is, run with `-i` or `-d` to get more info about what is going on and potentially find your problem.

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm no Android developer up to now, so this doesn't look familiar.